# What does it mean when a reference pointer is pointing to two different commits?

Tags: git, heroku, atlassian-sourcetree

I see `heroku/master`, in the image below, is pointing to two different commits and I am not sure why is this!
[image]

this happened after I ran the command `git branch -f heroku/master 67520d9f`. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: i think you got it the other way around. You have a single revision that is being pointed by 2 different pointers (a local branch and a remote one).

Comment: so the one colored with blue is the local and the one colored with red is the remote?

Comment: Oh.... _now_ I see what you are talking about. Would it be possible to use a terminal to check? Run `git branch -a` to see what is listed.

Comment: i get this `(HEAD detached at 67520d9f)
  heroku/master
  master
  remotes/heroku/master`

Comment: here you can see screenshot of what i got: https://imgur.com/a/tpWvWn5

Comment: do you know how can I make `heroku/master` and `remotes/heroku master` point to the same commit?

Comment: Is this command the last thing that you did? Do you just want to undo this?

Comment: @BugHunter I want to make `heroku/master` and `remotes/heroku` master point to the same commit

Comment: You have not answered my question.

Comment: no it is not the last command i did.

Comment: my problem is that whenever i push to heroku, i actually push the commit pointed by `heroku/master` with the red color. While I want to push the last commit, the one pointed by `heroku/master` with the blue color.

Comment: Try to run git checkout master

Comment: I am already on `master`. This is what i get `Already on 'master'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199980/discussion-between-bughunter-and-az-sh).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have created your own (local) branch named `heroku/master`, while also having a remote-tracking name<sup>1</sup> that is spelled `heroku/master`.

Technically, the *full* name of the *branch* is `refs/heads/heroku/master`.  The *full* name of the *remote-tracking name* is `refs/remotes/heroku/master`.  These full names are different, so it is possible to tell the two apart.  But it is confusing, as if you were at a party where everyone is named Bruce:

- BRUCE: Bruce!  How are you doing?  Have you met Bruce?
- BRUCE: No.  Hi Bruce!  How do you know Bruce?
- BRUCE: We both worked for Bruce for a while.

The solution to this problem is simple: use some other name(s) for your branch(es).  Rename your `heroku/master` branch to `h-master` for instance:

```
git branch -m heroku/master h-master
```

Now you'll have `master` and `h-master` as (local) branch names, and `heroku/master` reserved for the one remote-tracking name.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  They are your Git's memory of the branch names found on some other Git.  Your Git remembers the other Git under a name called a *remote*.  Your Git then takes their branch names—such as `master`—and changes them to use in your own work.  The changed names have the name of the remote stuck on the front of them, so that if you have a remote named `fred` and that other Git has a branch named `wilma`, you end up with `fred/wilma` as a remote-tracking name.

The most common remote name is `origin`, so most people wind up with a local `master` and a remote-tracking name, `origin/master`.  Some Git workflows call for a second remote, typically named `upstream`.  Heroku workflows call for a remote named `heroku`, which is why you have a remote named `heroku`.  Since your other Git named `heroku` has a branch named `master`, your Git will create `heroku/master` as your remote-tracking name for `heroku`'s `master`.